# How to create a URL on (and within) an overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

In a web application I'm working on, when someone wants to change their search location (for a map), they click on a button which brings up an overlay... the overlay has 3 tabs: Search by Location, Variables, and Stations.  What I am trying to do is have the url updated whenever the overlay is up and also change depending on which tab they are on.  This way when they share the URL, the exact overlay will be shown for the other person as well.

I've tried the push/replaceState() from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API , which updates the url; but when I close the overlay, the same url is still shown... also, when I try to go back to that same url, the overlay is not shown.

Any ideas will be appreciated.  Thank you!

Code... be advised I've tried several different scenarios which is why there's commented lines

```
// function addURL(element) {
//       $(element).attr('href', function() {
//             window.location.href = window.location +"&"+ "searrch";
//             // return window.location.href
//       });
// }

var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
function change_my_url()
{
      // history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 2", "#search");
      // Prevent default click action
      event.preventDefault();

      // Detect if pushState is available
      if(history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
      }
      return false;
}
var link = document.getElementById('nav-search-btn');

link.addEventListener('click', change_my_url, true);
```

Comment: Please provide a small demo of what you tried to illustrate your needs and what went wrong.

Comment: `pushState` is the correct thing to be using here. However the problem is clearly *how* you're using it, which you have not shown us. As such we cannot debug the problem.

Comment: Just updated the post